# Can I create Interface Properties as Generic?

Tags: c#, interface

Is there anyway to create such interface which generates properties as generic.

```
    public interface IInterface<T>
{
    string nameOf(T)+"_Email" { get; set; } // this won`t compile
    string nameOf(T)+"_Phone" { get; set; } // this won`t compile
}

public class Person
{
}

public class Details : IInterface<Person>
{
    public string Person_Email { get; set; }
    public string Person_Phone { get; set; }
}
```

---

I asked above question because my problem was as follow. I want to secure two classes with Interface contract. Then I combine these two classes in a ViewModel.  Viewmodel is not really helping because I need these properties on Razor. Please see below.

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
}

public interface IHotel
{
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel: IHotel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel1 : IPerson, IHotel
{
    //
    // This is missing either Person or Hotel details
    //
    public string Email { get ; set ; } 
    public string Phone { get ; set ; }
}

public class ViewModel2 : IPerson, IHotel
{
    //
    // This is ok but PUBLIC modifier is not allowed, I cannot use.
    //

    string IPerson.Email { get ; set ; } // public modifier not allowed
    string IHotel.Email { get ; set ; } // public modifier not allowed
    string IPerson.Phone { get ; set ; } // public modifier not allowed
    string IHotel.Phone { get ; set ; } // public modifier not allowed
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just letting the properties have the names "Email" and "Phone" should be fine...

Comment: I suppose it would be even hard to use those properties in case it would be even possible.

Comment: Say I have another classes like "Hotel", "Manager", "ResponsiblePerson". It would be beautiful if I would generate propertyNames based on Class name.

Comment: No, it would not be beautiful (i know, beauty is in the eye of the beholder). Look around in the .NET class libraries. Strings don't have a property/field `String_Length`. Arrays don't have a property/field `Array_Length`, etc.... There is no logical reason or benefit to have this: A manager has an email address, a manager doesn't have a "manager email address". A person has a phone number, a person doesn't have a "person phone number". ;-)

Comment: That said, what you want is simply not possible in C#/.NET :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible to dynamically modify the names of interface members with a class level generic argument.

Generics are designed to enable you to re-use the same functionality regardless of which generic type is specified. This is only possible if the interface remains consistent.

Consider this dilemma for example:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public string GetPhone(IInterface<T> bar)
    {
        // how would I know what method to call on foo here?
        return bar.????_Phone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how you can have generic properties in an interface. You  need a base class to translate for you and to bind the type you are looking for

```
public interface IInterface<T> where T : Contact
{
    string Email { get; }
    string Phone { get; }
}

public class Person : Contact
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class DetailsBase<T> : IInterface<T> where T : Contact
{
    Contact _cont { get; set; }
    public string Email { get { return _cont.Email; } }
    public string Phone { get { return _cont.Phone; } }
    public DetailsBase(Contact cont)
    {
        _cont = cont;
    }
}
public class Contact
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetails : DetailsBase<Person>
{
    public PersonDetails(Person person) : base(person)
    {

    }
}
```